# Trans junctions in fused cyclopentane rings

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is it possible for the ring junction to be trans in a molecule containing 2 fused cyclopentane rings? I am aware it is not possible for fused cyclobutane rings but am not sure about the 5-membered counterpart. In case the question isn't clear, the ring junction I am referring to is the one that has stereochemistry drawn in the decalin molecules below.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking whether [*trans*-octahydropentalene](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.19984498.html) exists?

Comment: @andselisk Yes, that is what I was asking, thank you for the insight. A lot of (probably bad) sources I have found have argued that it was impossible for some reason...

Comment: Maybe you want to answer the question yourself?